# What does already distant time mean?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

In this paragraph, what does **already distant time** mean?

```
This film takes place in an already distant time.
The story it tells could not happen today.
Discipline is no longer as severe in colleges, and the education
methods are very different.
But what will never change, what remains eternal, are
the emotions which test the threshold of adolescence
```

What are we talking about? future or past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text example is talking about **both** the **past** and the **future** by referencing **historic discipline** and **future passage into adolescence**.

References to **the past** in your example

> in an already distant time
>   could not happen today
>   no longer as severe

References to **the future** in your example

> will never change
>   remains eternal

Answer (score 1):

The "already" implies past tense.